# Vb.net, How to restart an application with elevated admin rights?

Tags: vb.net, admin

I currently have 2 applications; The main application and an Updater. The main application runs with the manifest in "asInvoker", whilst the Updater runs with "requireAdministrator".

However, I currently need the main program to modify contents of its own folder in ProgramFiles, but in order to do this I need elevated access. Instead of creating another application to separate the process, would it be possible to have a messagebox appear saying "Restart in Admin Mode?" and then proceed to restart the application in Administrative mode only the one time?

I don't want the end user being spammed with Window's UAC every time they open the application, which is why I already separated the updater.

Any ideas and suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it the actual program which needs to be updated or just some data which *could* be stored in a location which doesn't need admin access?

Comment: Does it have to be the main program that does the modifying, or can the updater do this as well?  Otherwise I suspect you're looking at a set of 3 programs - a loader, which decides what's needed and then starts the updater, the main program, or the main program as administrator.

Comment: There's an installation file in ProgramFiles which the main program needs to modify. Its a rare situation but I didn't want to have to make a new process for it

Answer (score 0):

Simpliest solution is to not store application in Program Files, where access is restricted for non-administrators, but in %LocalAppData%, where is unrestricted access for logged user. This is how update is solved in ClickOnce-distributed applications.